# How I can use only needed Fields from API with BootstrapVue?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, api, vue.js

I've a Array which is filled in with multipe fields from a express API by using axios. But I want to list only needed columns from my API using BootstrapVue.

I guess it has to resolved by doing it with a for loop but i dont know how should i implement it.

This includes the Data in JSON-format from the API:

```
data() {
  return {
    patients: [],
  }
}
```

This is the html code which shows the given columns and rows:

```html
<b-table striped hover :items="patients"></b-table>
```

Expected:

**Given fields (from API)**: Id, Name, Surname, Birthday, Email
**Needed fields**: Name, Surname, Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the `fields` property:

```
fields: ['name', 'surname', 'email']
```